# Row to Column in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do i transform rows into columns in sql server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344590/how-do-i-transform-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2005)

Table name `sa`

```
Number
10
20
30
40
```

Expected Result

```
Number  Number  Number  Number
10       20     30      40
```

Comment: Actually, that's technically row to column. It's almost a near certain indication that your schema was generated by a monkey pumped to the eyeballs with amphetamines :-)

Comment: Has been asked a **gazillion** times already on this site - please **SEARCH** before posting! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344590/how-do-i-transform-rows-into-columns-in-sql-server-2005, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946234/convert-database-rows-into-columns, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801895/sql-server-convert-rows-to-columns

Answer (score 0):

Try to this query

```
select number from sa
declare @s varchar(8000)
select  @s = COALESCE(@s + ',', '') + cast(number as varchar(10)) + ' as number'
from    sa
exec('select '+@s)
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
case when 10 then 10 
     when 20 then 20
     when 30 then 30
     when 40 then 40
     else
     ''
end
from tablenAme
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!